# Need regex to parse keyword='value' with single or double quotes

Tags: regex, quotes, preg-match

I'm having trouble writing a regular expression (suitable for PHP's preg_match()) that will parse keyword='value' pairs regardless of whether the <value> string is enclosed in single or double quotes. IOW in both of the following cases I need to get the <name> and <value> where the <value> string may contain the non-enclosing type of quotes:

```
name="value"
name='value'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Perl this is a regular expression that would work. It first matched for the start of the line then matches for one or more non = characters and sets them to $1. Next it looks for the = then the a non parentheses with a choice of matching for " or ' and sets that to $2.

```
/^([^=]+)=(?:"([^"]+)"|'([^']+)')$/
```

If you wanted it to match blank expressions like.

This=""

Replace the last two + with an * Otherwise this should work

**Edit**
As mentioned in the comments. Doug used...

```
 /^\s?([^=]+)\s?=\s?("([^"]+)"|\'([^\']+)\')\s?/
```

This will match one optional white space on ether end of the input or value and he has removed the end of line marker.

Comment: it will match name='asd" with a double quote at the and, that's not correct.

Comment: No longer matches non matching quote sets.

Comment: This isn't quite right. /^([^=]+)=(?:"([^"]+)"|'([^']+)')"$/
I believe the double quote before the end-of-line metacharacter shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Doug - It is a honor to be corrected by the publishers of IT Conversations :). Thanks corrected.

Comment: Here's the final version I used. It's escaped for single quotes and is more forgiving for whitespace. Thanks for the help!
/^\s?([^=]+)\s?=\s?("([^"]+)"|\'([^\']+)\')\s?/

Comment: I think the `name` in (`name="value"`) should not contains space(s). But your implementation did not take that into consideration.

Answer (score 4):

```
/^(\w+?)=(['"])(\w+?)\2$/
```

Which will place the key in `$1` and the value in `$3`.

Answer (score 1):

A few years late, but since this question is highly ranked on google, and the answers didn't satisfy my needs, here's another [expression](http://regex101.com/r/gP3hS7):

```
(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(['"]?)(?<val>(?:(?!\2)[^\\]|\\.|\w)+)\2
```

This will match single or double quotes, taking into account escaped quotes, and unquoted values.

```
name = bar
name = "bar"
name = 'bar'
name = "\"ba\"r\""
```

It, however, does have a limitation in that if a value is missing the key from the next key/value pair is read. This can be addressed by using a [comma separated list](http://regex101.com/r/lE4aB1) of key/value pairs.